# WPF Localization Extension

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, localization, .net-assembly

I've started using the WPF Localization Extension to localize my resources for WPF projects. I like the library because it can easily locate resource's out of the XAML-Code.

My project contains some assembly (one by specific view) and I want to use one dictionnary resource by assembly that contain the key specific to the assembly.
I have a problem on an assembly where I want to translate a DataGrid.

```
                <DataGrid>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="{lex:Loc Test}"  Width="Auto"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

In the usercontrol header:

```
         xmlns:lex="http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com"
         lex:ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultAssembly="MyModules.Test"
         lex:ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultDictionary="Resources"
```

The translation work in design time. But at runtime, I have the key:Test at the header text. After I click on one row of the grid, the translation is correctly updated and it work perfectly but I need to click on a row.
In other usercontrol of another assembly, I use a simple TextBlock and the translation work fine directly.

In the main assembly, I initialize the application:

```
        LocalizeDictionary.Instance.SetCurrentThreadCulture = true;
        LocalizeDictionary.Instance.SetCultureCommand.Execute("fr");
```

What I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

Answer from MrCircuit

> What you describe is a deeper problem of WPF: The DataGrid breaks the
>   Parent/Child relationship tree that is needed for Attached Property
>   retrieval. Therefore, the loc extensions inside the DataGrid can't
>   access the DefaultAssembly and DefaultDictionary values.
>
> Possible workarounds are: 
>   (A) to add these attached properties inside
>   of your DataGrid elements 
>   (B) to use the extended key syntax:
>   Assembly:Dictionary:Key
>   The option B that I have tested work fine.
>   Thanks